# AngularJS then() behaves differently than success()-error()

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

As the `success()` and `error()` functions are deprecated in AngularJS, I am updating my codes, replacing them with `then()`. Now according to my understanding, these two pieces of codes should behave identically:

```
$http
   .get(/* some params */)
   .success(function() {
      // success cases here
   })
   .error(function() {
      // error cases here
   });
```

And

```
$http
   .get(/* some params */)
   .then(function() {
      // success cases here
   }, function() {
      // error cases here
   });
```

But in some cases I am getting different behavior. Can you please explain to me why would that happen, and more importantly, what would be the way to guarantee the identical behavior using `then()` functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.success` and `.error` methods **ignore return values**.
Consequently they are **not suitable for chaining**.

```
var httpPromise = $http
       .get(/* some params */)
       .success(function onSuccess(data, status, headers, config) {
          var modifiedData = doModify(data);
          //return value ignored
          return modifiedData;
       })
       .error(function onError(data, status, headers, config) {
          // error cases here
       });

httpPromise.then(function onFullfilled(response) {
    //chained data lost
    //instead there is a response object
    console.log(response.data); //original data
    console.log(response.status); //original status
});
```

On the otherhand, the `.then` and `.catch` methods return a *derived promise* **suitable for chaining** from returned (or throw) values or from a new promise.

```
var derivedPromise = $http
       .get(/* some params */)
       .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
          console.log(response.data); //original data
          console.log(response.status); //original status

          var modifiedData = doModify(response.data);
          //return a value for chaining
          return modifiedData;
       })
       .catch(function onRejected(response) {
          // error cases here
       });

derivedPromise.then(function onFullfilled(modifiedData) {
    //data from chaining
    console.log(modifiedData);
});
```

### Response Object vs Four Arguments

Also notice that the `$http` service provides **four arguments** `(data, status, headers, config)` when it invokes the function provided to the `.success` and `.error` methods.

The `$q` service only provides **one argument** (response) to the functions provided to the `.then` or `.catch` methods. In the case of promises created by the `$http` service the response object has these properties:<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)</sup>

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

> ### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

---

## Update

The `.success` and `.error` methods have been deprecated and removed from AngularJS V1.6.

For more information, see

- [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 2):

One important difference is that you should probably use `.then().catch()` instead of `.then(function(), function())`. [1] The two-argument then (where the second function is the error handler) does not capture errors in the first function, as I understand it. IOW: `$http.get().then(a, b)` will not call b() if a() throws an error, where as `$http.get().then(a).catch(b)` will.

What other sorts of different behaviors are you getting?

1: standardized Promise API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

The success function and the promise callback indeed receive different objects. As described in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the promise callback receives a response object containing status, headers, data etc. The success function returns just the data field (the response body) of that object.